# Strange behavior of 'integrate' function

Tags: r, integrate

The following code is to calculate the expectation of a random variable of logit-normal distribution with parameters mu and sigma (mu is mu, and lsig is the logarithm of sigma).

```
fun5 = function(y,mu=mu0,lsig=lsig0) {
  res = exp(y)/(1+exp(y)) * 1/sqrt(2*pi)/exp(lsig) * exp(-(y-mu)^2/2/exp(lsig)^2)
  return(res)
}
el = 17
integrate(fun5,-el,el,mu=0.3434108,lsig=-3.5)$value
```

We should integrate this function from negative infinity to positive infinity, but I don't know how to do so and know only to integrate for finite interval. 
Thus, I try to integrate from 'wide enough' interval (from -el to +el).
When the 'el' is greater than 0.5, it seems to work reasonably (true value of this integration is 0.585).
But when el is 14 and 15, this works weirdly. Does anybody know why this happens?

```
> el = 10
> integrate(fun5,-el,el,mu=0.3434108,lsig=-3.5)$value
[1] 0.585
> el = 13
> integrate(fun5,-el,el,mu=0.3434108,lsig=-3.5)$value
[1] 0.585
> el = 14
> integrate(fun5,-el,el,mu=0.3434108,lsig=-3.5)$value
[1] 2.975338e-05
> el = 15
> integrate(fun5,-el,el,mu=0.3434108,lsig=-3.5)$value
[1] 1.134474e-05
> el = 16
> integrate(fun5,-el,el,mu=0.3434108,lsig=-3.5)$value
[1] 0.585
```

Comment: You can just use `integrate(fun5, -Inf, Inf, mu = 0.3434108, lsig = -3.5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if you understand that R designers allow `-Inf` and `Inf` as bounds and in fact encourages user to employ them, especially when one or both of those bounds is far from what might be called the "predominant support":

```
> integrate(fun5,-Inf,Inf, mu=0.3434108, lsig=-3.5)$value
[1] 0.585
```

Comment: I didn't know that Inf and -Inf are allowed. This solves my current problem. But I still wonder why that weird results occurred.

Comment: (I think) : If the limits are chosen in a range where the variation of values is minimal it messes up the calculation of gradients which are needed for some of the algorithms that do the adaptive calculations. I am happy to hear more informed answers than this "handwaving" response. But if this answer was useful you should at a minimum upvote it. And, even more importantly, you should go through you other questions that had on point answers and upvote them, too.